# Can I get files from "Depot" without a "Stream" in Perforce P4?

Tags: perforce

So I've been reading the helix-core documentation for the p4 command line tool because I cannot use the visual client on my current machine. I am trying to get a way to get the latest files from the local depot on the server, which stores the project me and my team are working on.

I have found the `sync` command but it requires a stream. I never had to define one when I set up the visual clients for the team or the server if I recall correctly and so if I had one I couldn't find it. The administration tool only shows me the depot like this: `//depot/myFiles`, which is the default local depot that is created when the server is created if I'm not mistaken. So I've been wondering if it's possible to just "get latest" like in the visual client without a stream or how I can find the stream this depot is using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr: the thing you want to make is a "workspace", not a "stream".  Run `p4 client` to create a workspace.**

Depots come in two basic flavors in Perforce: `stream` and `local` (aka "classic").  The type of a depot is set when it's created by the Perforce admin.  One server can have any number of depots.

In a `stream` depot, files are organized into streams, which by default take the form of top-level depot directories, e.g. `//stream/main` and `//stream/rel1`.  Streams can be configured to represent files beyond what's in the actual depot directories, but in their simplest form each stream just corresponds exactly to a directory in the depot, including one `mainline` stream and usually many other streams that are branched from the mainline.  *Every file in a stream depot is inside a stream.*  You can run the `p4 streams` command to see a list of all the streams.

In a `local` depot, there are no streams.  You can add any file anywhere.  Usually files are organized into parallel top level directories that are branched from each other, e.g. `//local/main` and `//local/rel1`, but there are no guard rails that steer you toward this.

In any kind of depot, you need to create a **client workspace** to sync and submit files.  Each workspace has a **client view** which creates a mapping between depot files and workspace files; the client view takes depot files and puts them into your workspace when you sync, and it takes workspace files and puts them into the depot when you submit.  Each workspace is unique to a particular directory on a particular client machine (the **client root**) -- you must create a new workspace for each local machine you do work on!

- In a `stream` depot, when you create a workspace, you specify the **Stream** that you're going to work on.  A **client view** is generated for you automatically that maps your workspace root to the files in the stream.  You are not allowed to modify this view manually; if you want to change the view, you need to change the stream, and this will automatically update the views of all clients associated with that stream (so one stream may have many clients, but they will always share a consistent view -- the main function of streams is to centralize client view management).
- In a `local` depot, when you create a workspace, you define a **View** yourself.  By default, when you create a workspace on a server that has a single local depot, the client view maps the entire depot to the workspace root.  You can edit the **View** yourself to map arbitrary paths in the depot to arbitrary paths within your workspace, so you have complete control over which depot files you sync and where each one goes.

To create a client workspace from the command line, run:

```
p4 client
```

This will open an editor that contains the client spec.  Edit the **Stream** or **View** field appropriately.  Note that the default name of the client workspace is the hostname of your client machine that it lives on; if you want to change this, run `p4 set P4CLIENT=your-client-name` before running `p4 client`.  Save the client spec, exit the editor, and you'll see a message like "client saved".

Now you can sync:

```
p4 sync
```

This will use your current client spec (the one you've just defined) to sync files from the depot into your workspace.  You only need to create the client spec the first time you set up a new client machine, but you can run `p4 client` again at any time to modify it.

Comment: Thank you for your time Sam. I've gotten to the client setup before but haven't defined the View correctly. It's synching now.